# Filter low amplitude noise from signal

Tags: filter, signals, noise

From a step signal, I want to

1. filter the low amplitude random noise
2. preserve the edge
3. preserve the overshoot

For that, I tried several filters (Butterworth low pass, Median, Savgol). All can be adjusted to preserve edge and overshoot but still some lower frequency ripple remains.

Can you suggest another approch or a follow up procedure, yielding better results?

As a framework I use python/numpy/scipy but information on the general approach is appreciated.

[image: Sample signal and filter comarison]

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem for a pressure sensor signal, in a RealTime OS + C environment ( no Matlab ).
I am still thinking about a de-bouncing logic and creating a histerezis: a moving time window and delta-pressure.

Comment: Hysteresis sounds like a good keyword. Using this as a search keyword I found "change band filtering" (https://gregstanleyandassociates.com/whitepapers/FaultDiagnosis/Filtering/Hysteresis-Filters/hysteresis-filters.htm) but no further information on that topic. With "delta-pressure" you mean the digitally differentiated pressure? How you're gonna use this?